# MongoDB regex query returns no results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say we have a collection initialised with one entry

```
db.test.insert({text:"why does this not work"})
```

So it looks like this

```
db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d500b384a6859f9a9bfbc1"), "text" : "why does this not work" }
```

And a query which looks like

```
db.test.find({"text":/.*why.*/})
```

I'm expecting that this will pick up the first record, but it doesn't. Any ideas why not?

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  But you don't need the `.*` parts anyway as `/why/` matches the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support '.'. Use [\s\S] instead. That actually means: whatever is a space or whatever is not a space.

EDIT: Although your example works just fine. I've encountered the above problem with Javascript and [\s\S] fixed it. Just try it.

Comment: Javascript regexes absolutely supports the `.` character class. If used inside braces, it'll mean a literal period, though. Perhaps that was the issue?

Comment: You're right. The issue I had was different: . doesn't match newlines while [\s\S] does. In this case there's no newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
> db.test.insert({text: "this is some sample text"})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d50b85499df584cc266f9a"), "text" : "this is some sample text" }
> db.test.find({text: /sample/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d50b85499df584cc266f9a"), "text" : "this is some sample text" }
> db.test.find({text: /.*sample.*/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d50b85499df584cc266f9a"), "text" : "this is some sample text" }
```

Even your exact sample works:

```
> db.test.insert({text:"why does this not work"})
> db.test.find({"text":/.*why.*/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d50c4c499df584cc266f9b"), "text" : "why does this not work" }
```

Perhaps you've overlooked something else?